# RegularExpression - Match characters not digits

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match a string followed by multiple tabs and another string.  The second string cannot have any digits.

So I'd like 'someText\t\tsomeText2' -> someText & somteText2

I have the following JavaScript:

```
var linePattern = /(^[^\s].+?)\t+([^\d].+)/
var regexp = new RegExp(linePattern);
var parts = 'someText\t\t1234'.match(regexp);
```

Not sure why it actually matches...It shouldn't...

Comment: for future reference: https://regex101.com/ is a nice tool for testing and figuring your regex patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `.+` at the last will match also the digits.

```
^(.*?)\t\t+(\D+)$
```

OR

```
^(.*?)\t+(\D+)$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vP3gT1/1)

Your regex,

```
    (^             [^\s]               .+?)               \t+                          ([^\d].+)
                     ^                  ^                 ^
   Start           Matches the   Matches all the chars  Matches only the first tab  since the second character must not be a non-digit character. So `[^\d]` matches the second tab. and the `.+` matches all the chars upto the last. Finally you got a match.
            first non-space      upto the  first tab
              character.
```

**Code:**

```
> var linePattern = /^(.*?)\t+(\D+)$/;
undefined
> var regexp = new RegExp(linePattern);
undefined
> var parts = 'someText\t\t1234'.match(regexp);
undefined
> parts
null
> var parts = 'someText\t\tfoo'.match(regexp);
undefined
> parts
[ 'someText\t\tfoo',
  'someText',
  'foo',
  index: 0,
  input: 'someText\t\tfoo' ]
```

Answer (score 1):

`([^\d].+)` is actually matching the tab (*any character except digits*) after the first matched tab in the string then the greedy `.+` will continue consuming and match the digits in the string.

Also, you do not need to use a RegExp object here, a regular expression literal is enough.

You can modify the regular expression and syntax as follows:

```
var re = /^(.*?)\t+(\D+)$/
var parts = str.match(re);
```

**Note:** Using both beginning of string `^` and end of string `$` anchors here is important.